# Apply multiple conditions and null value check in Linq query

Tags: linq, multiple-select-query

Need to check If body data Null and if Null filed, no need to check the particular WHERE clause.
How can I add multiple WHERE and OR clauses with NULL checking?
In `CountryDialCodeFields`, some fields can be null sometimes.

```
 public class CountryDialCodeFields
    {
        public string countryCode { get; set; }
        public string countryName { get; set; }
        public string dialCode { get; set; }
        public string currencyCode { get; set; }
    }


[HttpGet("/api/country-details")]
public IActionResult CountryDetailGet(CountryDialCodeFields BodyData)
{
var CountryDataSet22 = CountryCodeDbContext.Countrydetails.Where( x => (BodyData.countryCode != null ? x.Countrycode == BodyData.countryCode) &&
             (BodyData.countryName != null ? x.Countryname == BodyData.countryName) &&
             (BodyData.currencyCode != null ? x.Currencycode == BodyData.currencyCode) &&
             (BodyData.currencyCode != null ? x.Dialcode == BodyData.dialCode));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward way:

```cs
var CountryDataSet22 = CountryCodeDbContext.Countrydetails
    .Where(x => 
            (BodyData.countryCode  == null || x.Countrycode  == BodyData.countryCode)  &&
            (BodyData.countryName  == null || x.Countryname  == BodyData.countryName)  &&
            (BodyData.currencyCode == null || x.Currencycode == BodyData.currencyCode) &&
            (BodyData.dialCode     == null || x.Dialcode     == BodyData.dialCode)
    );
```

Or using extension:

```cs
public static class MyQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryble<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, bool condiion, Expression<Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            source = source.Where(predicate);
        return source;
    }
}
```

```cs
var CountryDataSet22 = CountryCodeDbContext.Countrydetails
    .WhereIf(BodyData.countryCode  != null, x => x.Countrycode  == BodyData.countryCode)
    .WhereIf(BodyData.countryName  != null, x => x.Countryname  == BodyData.countryName)
    .WhereIf(BodyData.currencyCode != null, x => x.currencyCode == BodyData.currencyCode)
    .WhereIf(BodyData.dialCode     != null, x => x.Dialcode     == BodyData.dialCode);
```

Comment: If you're going to write an extension, why not another `WhereIfNotNull`?

Comment: @NetMage, good point.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv, I tried using extension. It's working. Thank you very much..